# Set coordinates of element in DIV with js, css, html

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

im working on some graphic representation of journal issues. What I need is to display block of text using simple DIVs (or else) inside of other DIV, exactly the way they are organized on issue page. To do that I need to set coordinates of DIV element to exact number, but in relation to parent DIV. Is there any way to do that by using css or js??

Comment:  ,     [ask] &    [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you outer div is set to `position: relative`, you can have the inside div as `position: absolute` and set its top, left, right and bottom properties to the pixels you need. For example.

```css
 .outer {
      position: relative;
    }

    .inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px; //your coordinate
      left: 5px; //your coordinate
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">Your content</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can simply use padding on the inner element.

Comment: Are those coordinate (10px, 5px) offsets of edge of parent DIV or window?

Comment: Offsets of the edge of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `div` to be `display: block;`, you can use simple `margin-top` and `margin-left` to set coordinates.

Lets say (for example) you need to set the coordinates of the `div` as <100,50>:

To do that, in CSS, set `margin-left: 100px` and `margin-top: 50px`